# How to include net_rim_api_wlan_hotspot in my BB project?

Tags: build, wifi, blackberry-jde

I have a project that is going to create hotspot client, so it imports net.rim.device.api.wlan.hotspot.*

When the code runs it complains that it cannot find net_rim_api_wlan_hotspot.  If I display the table-of-contents for the jar file, *\BlackBerry JDE 5.0.0\lib\net_rim_api.jar, the file class files are listed.

What steps am I missing to build the project correctly?